# gxt tooltip doesn't work in IE9

Tags: java, gwt, tooltip, gxt

Here is my code:

```
TextField<String> textField = new TextField<String> textField();
```

`textField.markInvalid("Error text");`

I've faced the next issue - in IE 9 it shown only textfield marked with red color, but it doesn't show error icon and tooltip for this icon. I've read the Field class and tried to rewrite error icon WidgetComponent in my own class, but I haven't succeeded.